# How to extract max value among values between 2 words with multiple occurrence from input string using shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression

I want to extract the maximum temperature value from the output of a command, which I store in a shell variable as follows:

```
res="$(get temperature all)"
```

where the result looks like

```
 Device 0 avs data:
    Temperature: 33.5 C
    voltage1V0:  0.926 V
    voltage1V8:  1.782 V
    voltage3V3:  3.265 V

 Device 1 avs data:
    Temperature: 32.6 C
    voltage1V0:  0.923 V
    voltage1V8:  1.780 V
    voltage3V3:  3.265 V

 Device 2 avs data:
    Temperature: 33.1 C
    voltage1V0:  0.920 V
    voltage1V8:  1.785 V
    voltage3V3:  3.290 V

 Device 3 avs data:
    Temperature: 33.1 C
    voltage1V0:  0.921 V
    voltage1V8:  1.780 V
    voltage3V3:  3.265 V
```

I want to extract the numerical value enclosed between the strings `Temperature:` and `C`, and find the maximum value from all the device records. For the above case, the output should be

```
33.5
```

since the temperature values are 33.5, 32.6, 33.1, 33.1

In the above command, the output gives

- sometimes only `Device 0` information,
- sometimes `Device 0`, `Device 1` information
- sometimes  `Device 0`, `Device 1`, `Device 3`, `Device 4` information

so finding max temperature logic should be generic irrespective of devices count (though the max count is 4, min count is 1 for available devices).

So for example, if only a single device is present then the max temperature should be equal to device 0 temperature, otherwise we need to compare and print.

**Edit 1** - I need to use `sed` or `awk` as `grep -P` option is not available.

```
echo 'Here is a string, and Here is another string.' | grep -oP '(?<=Here).*(?=string)'

grep: invalid option -- 'P'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please indicate what you have already tried, in order to avoid that contributors trying to help point you in a direction which you already know doesn't work. When editing your question to do so, please indicate which tools you have at your disposal (`awk`, `sed`, `perl`, ...).

Comment: @AdminBee I tried to do it using grep like this but `"echo 'Here is a string, and Here is another string.' | grep -oP '(?<=Here).*(?=string)'`
  grep: invalid option -- 'P'" . So looks like -p is not available on my system. so need to use awk or sed instead.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming every device can contain *only one* "Temperature" reading, and you are only interested in printing the maximum (and not the associated device number), you can try the following:

```
awk '$1=="Temperature:" {if ($2>max) max=$2} END{printf("Maximum: %.1f\n",max)}'
```

This will parse all lines where the first space-separated field (`$1`) is `Temperature:`, and inspect the second field (`$2`, which is the numerical temperature value). If that is larger than the maximum so far, it is stored in the variable `max` (which behaves as if it were initially 0).

At the end, this maximum found is printed.